# How to completely remove a package in Debian?

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, aptitude, dpkg

I tried to use this:

```
aptitude remove denyhosts
```

And it seemed successfully but after a reboot after I use:

```
ps aux | grep "denyhosts"
```

I see denyhosts is still loaded after startup.

So what am I supposed to do so that I can stop and destroy it once and for all? "aptitude remove something" isn't meant for uninstalling?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Will remove a package and all configuration files.

```
apt-get --purge remove package
```

If it is still giving you issues, try reinstalling then purging:

```
apt-get --reinstall install package
apt-get --purge remove package
```

You still might need to:

```
killall package
```

Reboot and if it started again run:

```
update-rc.d remove package
```

Story Time: Once for some unknown reason, when I purge removed ejabberd; it continued running. I trusted apt-get to kill it and remove it. It didn't. Needless to say, it eventually filled up my entire /var with a ramdisk log file. It continued until I killed all of the ejabberd processes and that quickly resolved the issue. So it taught me to always be sure that apt-get worked and killed all needed processes.

Comment: Just so you know, aptitude is the preferred package manager in Debian.

Comment: apt-get, aptitude, and dpkg are all preferred package managers for Debian. It doesn't really matter much anymore as it has before. If Debian really only wanted a single package manager, they would symlink one of them to the others and teach the new one the same switches.

Answer (score 4):

In case you prefer `aptitude`:

```
# aptitude purge denyhosts
```

purge should also remove the init scripts, so the `update-rc.d` step is not really necessary.

Another thing that is possible that another package also provides a daemon called denyhosts. To search for all installed packages that contain files with `denyhosts` in them:

```
$ dpkg -S denyhosts
```

Comment: Spelling...

Comment: Thanks, but _IF_ you want to help, point out where somebody misspelled something, don't make them scan the entire post. If you just want to bitch about some non-native speaker making a mistake, have fun.

Comment: i would guess that the spelling mistake he's referring to is "dpgk" instead of "dpkg" - it's a typing mistake i make frequently when i'm typing too fast.  often enough that i've got used to typing "^gk^kg<ENTER>" to fix it.

Comment: Thanks Craig. I thought it was deamon <-> daemon - that's a mistake I frequently make. When I misstype dpkg my zsh kindly asks me if it is allowed to correct my mistake, but Serverfault currently misses that feature ;-)

Comment: Thanks!
I found that apt-get couldn't really get rid of the package completely as I installed it with 'aptitude install' in the first place.
apatitude purge denyhosts successfully removed the package completely!

Comment: @kavoir.com "apt-get couldn't really get rid of the package completely" <---- this is just wrong.