# I can't get rid of apache2

Tags: debian, apache-2.2, apt, uninstall, remove

It's obvious that I am a newbie with server administration; my goal is to reach the knowledge needed to working with web services.

I played with my Debian server, and I messed up apache2; Now I want to completely* remove it from the server and then reinstall it as new.

*by completely i really mean **completely**, logs, configurations, settings, everything!

I followed the steps suggested by freedom_is_chaos in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/62691/how-to-completely-remove-a-package-in-debian), and I guess apache2 is no longer installed, because if I do `apt-get remove apache2`, I get this:

```
# apt-get remove apache2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package apache2 is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.

# dpkg --remove apache2
dpkg - warning: ignoring request to remove apache2 which isn't installed.
# dpkg --purge apache2
dpkg - warning: ignoring request to remove apache2 which isn't installed.
```

Then, I rebooted the server, and:

```
# netstat -plant
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
[...]
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      3467/apache2
[...]
```

WTF? is apache2 still here? So it seems:

```
# /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
Stopping web server: apache2.
```

But:

```
# update-rc.d remove apache2
update-rc.d: /etc/init.d/remove: file does not exist
```

So, what is happening to my server? How can I completely and truly remove apache2 from my server?

**EDIT: As usually happens, the problem was between the chair and the keyboard ;)**

I don't know how, but while I was 'playing' with the server configuration I installed apache2.2 by mistake, `dpkg -l | grep 'apache'` showed me some other libs still installed; once I removed them, I've been able to completely remove and reinstall apache2 (with the `--purge` option).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try

```
sudo apt-get remove apache2 --purge
```

and for removing the rc.d files try

```
sudo update-rc.d apache2 remove -f
```

Comment: updated my question

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
sudo aptitude purge ~iapache2
```

Although this would have been sufficient:

```
sudo update-rc.d apache2 disable
```